# I want to encrypt this file but the output is missing

Tags: c++, encryption

After I execute the following code, my `out.txt` appears to be missing, I don't know what to do.

```
void Cripto::cipher(string path, byte key){
  ifstream file;

  file.open(path);
  file.seekg(0, file.end);
  long size = file.tellg();
  file.seekg(0);

  byte * characters = new byte[size];
  setCharacters(characters);
  file.read(characters, size);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      characters[i] += getKey();
  }

  ofstream outfile("out.txt");
  outfile.write(characters, size);
}
```

Comment: Well, you could add some error checking, some logs, run it in the debugger, provide a [mcve], etc.

Comment: Yeah, i tried a few things, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things you can do to troubleshoot your problem.

1. If you are on POSIX system, use [`getcwd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) to retrieve the current working directory and print it to the terminal. That will give you an idea of where the program is trying to open the files.
2. Make sure the files are opened successfully.
3. Don't assume that reading of the data from the input file was successful. Capture the number of characters that were successfully read and use it.

---

```
void Cripto::cipher(string path, byte key)
{
   // Print current working directory.
   char cwd[1000];
   getcwd(cwd, 1000);
   std::cout << "Current working directory: " << cwd << std::endl;

   ifstream file;
   file.open(path);
   if ( !file )
   {
      // Problem opening the file.
      // Throw an exception and get out of the function.
      throw std::runtime_error("Unable to open file for reading from");
   }

   file.seekg(0, file.end);
   long size = file.tellg();
   file.seekg(0);

   byte * characters = new byte[size];
   setCharacters(characters);
   long n = file.gcount();

   // Only n characters were read.
   if ( n != size )
   {
      // Print a warning message.
   }

   // Encrypt only the number of characters that were read.
   if ( n != size )
   {
      // Print a warning message.
   }

   // Encrypt only the number of characters were read.
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      characters[i] += getKey();
   }

   ofstream outfile("out.txt");
   if ( !outfile )
   {
      // Problem opening the file.
      // Throw an exception and get out of the function.
      throw std::runtime_error("Unable to open file for writing to");
   }

   // Write n characters, not size.
   outfile.write(characters, n);
}
```

Comment: `seek` can fail. If `open` fails, mention the filename and the reason for the failure in the error message.

Comment: thanks a lot! it was a std::bad_alloc error

Comment: @BielBorba, Ah. How easily can we fail to notice that!